# Use HttpExchangeRepository to save HttpExchange objects in a relational DB in Spring Boot 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In spring boot actuator, I am using `InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository` to trace http requests. I use the following Bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class ActuatorConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public HttpExchangeRepository httpTraceRepository()
    {
        InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository repository = new InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository();
        repository.setCapacity(1000);
        return repository;
    }
}
```

Can i use `HttpExchangeRepository` to persist HttpExchange objects in a relational database (MySQL, PostgreSQL etc)? I want to use either Spring jdbc or Spring Data JPA.

I am using Spring Boot 3.0.2

Comment: have you tried the solution you propose ? what's the result? share the result to help address the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote from [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.http-exchanges):

> You can enable recording of HTTP exchanges by providing a bean of type HttpExchangeRepository in your application’s configuration. For convenience, Spring Boot offers InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository, which, by default, stores the last 100 request-response exchanges. InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository is limited compared to tracing solutions, and we recommend using it only for development environments. For production environments, we recommend using a production-ready tracing or observability solution, such as Zipkin or OpenTelemetry. Alternatively, you can create your own HttpExchangeRepository. You can use the httpexchanges endpoint to obtain information about the request-response exchanges that are stored in the HttpExchangeRepository.

So, HttpExchangeRepository is not meant to be persisted manually on a database (unless you want to implement your own tracing system, but there are open-source systems available).

In order to handle the burden of saving and using the http exchanges, you should use one the following: [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/), [OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/), [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/), [WaveFront](https://docs.wavefront.com/tracing_basics.html) or other...